# Command to transmit Data over wlan

Tags: wifi

I am doing some experiment for which I need to collect Data from wlan driver.

I am interested in transmitting IEEE 802.11b Packets with more flexibility in terms of Data Rate, Packet Size etc.

Basically, I will have the laptop as the transmitter and I have built a custom receiver for IEEE 802.11b  which would read the packets ( IEEE 802.11b 1/2/5.5 or 11Mbps) .

So, I am looking at some Linux tool which gives the option of setting these parameters while transmitting data.

I am thinking at commands like iwpriv to set the parameters for the wireless driver,  and iperf commands to generate Traffic.

I am not sure, how to use them to achieve a Data traffic, say 1Mbps / and 1024 Bytes PSDU (Packet Size).

The receiver is a dedicated hardware ( not a Computer). Any suggestion or idea in this direction would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use [wireshark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark) or pcap (via perl,python etc) to capture what you want.

Comment: Hi, I do not want to capture the Packets in the System. I have built a model which I plan to test. Its a dedicated hardware. I am looking at a tool which gives me transmitting Packets with more flexibility in terms of choosing the Data Rate etc..

Comment: `I am interested in collecting IEEE 802.11b Packets.` was your question. You could write a tool you require using pcap as I explained.

Answer (score 1):

You may be better off asking this on Server Fault. I found a couple of packet generators that look like they could do what you need but I'm by no means an expert.

[packETH](http://packeth.sourceforge.net/):

> - you can create and send any ethernet packet [...]
> - sending sequence of packets
>
>   - delay between packets, number of packets to send
>   - sending with max speed, approaching the teoretical boundary
>   - change parameters while sending (change IP & mac address, UDP payload, 2 user defined bytes, etc.)

[Ostantino](http://code.google.com/p/ostinato/):

> - Modify any field of any protocol (some protocols allow changing packet fields with every packet at run time e.g. changing IP/MAC addresses)
>     [...]
> - Configure stream rates, bursts, no. of packets

I found these in the [Wireshare Wiki](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Tools#Traffic_generators) where there are a number of other tools that may help.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ben.. I will try these tools. Hopefully, I will succeed. When I thought about it looked pretty straight forward. But I did not knew how to do it since I am not expert as well with all the adaptive Rate Modulation Techniques and ISM band and channel selectivity.

Comment: Mmm. That makes two of us :-/ Good luck!

Comment: I was just trying to look at various options associated with `iwconfig` command. I think, this might be interesting for what I was looking for.